# On root systems

Tags: root-systems

Consider the following definition of a **root system** from Brian C. Hall, *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations*, GTM 222.

> [image]

By 4. it follows that $\omega_\alpha(R)\subset R$. But later on, the author claims:

> [image]

I agree that $\alpha = \omega_\alpha\cdot (\omega_\alpha \cdot \alpha)$ but I can not follow why this implies the *onto* statement.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the book. It should be $\beta\in R\implies \beta = w_\alpha\cdot(w_\alpha\cdot \beta)$. That will give the desired _onto_ implication.

Comment: @theindigamer Hopefully, it is a typo. I think that the question is closed now. Anyway, we can prove the *onto* part using your equality. Thanks.